# Segmentation fault assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, intel

I am getting a segmentation fault for the following assembly code which simply prints out a message though the printing is handled by a separate function so I'm quite sure I'm not allocating the right space on the stack for the message and the length.

Here is the code:

```
section .data
    print_msg:      DB "H", 10, 0
    len:            equ $-print_msg 
    print_msg2:     DB "BYE WORLD", 10, 0
    len2:           equ $-print_msg2


section .text

    global main

main:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    push DWORD len
    push print_msg
    call _write

    push DWORD len2
    push print_msg2
    call _write

    leave
    ret

_write:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp   

    push ebx
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, [ebp+8]
    mov edx, [ebp+12]
    int 80h
    pop ebx

    leave 
    ret
```

Comment: Won't `push print_msg` push a pointer, and not the chars?

Comment: @James: Indeed it will. Another problem is that the `ebp`-relative offsets inside `_write` are wrong (the old `ebp` will be at `[ebp+0]`, and the return address will be at `[ebp+4]`).

Comment: @James Oh and so the pointer is only 4 bytes?

Comment: @Michael so do you think I should get rid of pushing ebp within the _write and just sort out the offsets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need to allocate any space on the stack because `push` will do that for you.
2. `push DWORD [len]` is wrong because it tries to dereference `len` which is just a number.
3. `mov ecx, [ebp+2]` and `mov edx, [ebp+6]` are using wrong offsets, they should be `+8` and `+12`, respectively. Stack layout from `ebp` is: `saved_ebp`, `return address`, `arg1`, `arg2` (4 bytes each)

Like so:

```
section .data
    print_msg:      DB "H", 10, 0
    len:            equ $-print_msg

section .text

    global main
main:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push DWORD len
    push print_msg
    call _write
    leave
    ret

_write:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, [ebp+8]
    mov edx, [ebp+12]
    int 80h
    leave
    ret
```

PS: C calling convention mandates you should preserve `ebx`, so the `_write` function should save and restore it.

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand, I've been following tutorials where we need to physically allocate space for items to be pushed onto the stack.

Comment: Oh so I should push ebx on the stack and then restore it outside the function.

Comment: You can allocate space, but then you should use `mov` to write to this space and not `push`. Make sure you allocate 4 bytes for each argument, too. For saving/restoring `ebx` you should `push` and `pop` it inside _write itself, I recommend after the `mov ebp, esp` and before the `leave`, respectively.

Comment: I have extended my code and tried to sort restore ebx values, have I done it right, it works just wondering about ebx restoration.

Comment: You still have the unnecessary space allocation, and you haven't put the ebx save/restore where I told you. But it works :)

Comment: I actually got rid of the space allocation just forgot to get rid of it in the above code. I've finally sorted the restoration of ebx code. Thanks for helping.